# Incorporating Expression<> in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, .net-5

I'm trying to incorporate an `Expression` in a LINQ query.

```
Expression<Func<RailcarTrip, DateTime?>>? getDateProperty = Search.GetDateProperty();
if (getDateProperty != null)
{
    if (Search.StartDate.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(rt => getDateProperty(rt) >= Search.StartDate);
    if (Search.EndDate.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(rt => getDateProperty(rt) <= Search.EndDate);
}

public Expression<Func<RailcarTrip, DateTime?>>? GetDateProperty()
{
    return DateType switch
    {
        TripDateType.Waybill => rt => rt.WaybillRailcar.Waybill.CreateDate,
        TripDateType.Delivery => rt => rt.DeliveryDate,
        TripDateType.Release => rt => rt.ReleaseDate,
        TripDateType.Return => rt => rt.ReturnDate,
        TripDateType.ReturnRelease => rt => rt.ReturnReleaseDate,
        _ => null,
    };
}
```

But this won't compile. Using `getDateProperty()` as I have in my LINQ query is not supported.

Can anyone show me how I could make this work?

I have found examples on the web that resolved this by passing the `Expression<>` directly, rather than using it in an expression. But in my case, I'm comparing the result to something else.

I think I can pass the date to `GetDateProperty()` and incorporate it into the expression there. But then I need different versions of my method for each comparison type.

Comment: Is `query.AsEnumerable().Where` working?

Comment: `DateType`? That's a very old visual basic thing right?!? Why are you using it? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @JHBonarius: It's just an enum. Nothing to do with Visual Basic.

Comment: @viveknuna: That code would retrieve every row and then apply the filter. Definitely not what I want here.

Comment: Hmm, it is [a deprecated class of the .NET framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.datetype), even there in .net 5 (remember that VB.NET and C#.NET are connected). You should probably choose a more specific name for a custom type. Anyhow, does the duplicate question help you?

Comment: @JHBonarius: It's an enum member of the same class, so there's no conflict with the name. And, in this case, the name makes sense. The duplicate is some help.